# Surjectivity of map

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, polynomials

How to prove, that map 
$$\mathbb{R}[x] \to \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{C}$$ 
$$f \mapsto (f(-1), f(1 + i))$$
is surjective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ is mapped to $(a+c-b,(b+c)+(2a+b)i)$. I claim that these quadratic polynomials alone map to all of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{C}$. To prove this, show that for any $(x,y+zi)  \in \mathbb{R} \times\mathbb{C}$ (where $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$), it is of the form $(a+c-b,(b+c)+(2a+b)i)$ for some $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$. That is, $x=a+c-b$, $y=b+c$, and $z=2a+b$. This is now a linear algebra problem.